# Ember JS cannot createRecord with new ember-data syntax

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to use the new ember-data syntax like explained here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md (read from **Transaction is Gone: Save Individual Records** ).

When I hit the save button I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'save' of undefined` in the console. Also in the network tab, there is no POST request to the api.

**The template**

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="landcode/new">
    Code: {{input value=code}}<br />
    Image: {{input value=image}}<br />
<button {{action 'saveLandcode'}}>opslaan</button>
```

**The app.js** (relevant code)

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("landcodes"),
    this.resource("landcode", function() {
        this.route("new");
    });
});

App.LandcodeNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        this.store.createRecord('landcode');
    },
    actions: {
        saveLandcode: function(){
            this.modelFor('landcode').save(); // does not save
        }
    }
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api'
});
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'App.ApplicationAdapter'
});

App.Landcode = DS.Model.extend({
    code: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `this.modelFor('landcode')` this will take the returned model from `App.LandcodeRoute`, but your model is returned from `LandcodeNewRoute`. Just use `this.currentModel`, since you want the model of the current route.

```
App.LandcodeNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('landcode');
    },
    actions: {
        saveLandcode: function(){
            this.currentModel.save();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Both thanks for the answer. However both solutions give the same error as before. I go to setup a jsFiddle, then it will be clear to everyone what is going on.

Comment: I saw in your code that you are missing the `return` in this.store.createRecord ... Did you update your current implementation?

Comment: Hi Márcio, thanks for that last comment! Indead, I had missed that return statement you added. 
I removed my last JS Bin comment, setting up a Ember.js app on jsFiddle or JS Bin is a very unpleasant activity by the way.

Now we have found the bug, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Your model for should include the route name as well

```
App.LandcodeNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('landcode');
    },
    actions: {
        saveLandcode: function(){
            this.modelFor('landcode.new').save(); // the correct model
        }
    }
});
```