# can not delete record using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i cannot delete record using RESTAdapter.

Model:

```
Blog.Post = DS.Model.extend({
title:DS.attr('string'),
body:DS.attr('string'),
date:DS.attr('date')
});
```

ApplicationAdapter:

```
Blog.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
host:'http://localhost:8080',
namespace: 'api',
serializer: Blog.ApplicationSerializer
});
```

I have a button with action:

```
<button {{action deletePost this target="controller"}}>Delete post</button>
```

And controller:

```
Blog.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions:{
        deletePost: function () {
            var post = this.get('model');
            post.deleteRecord();
            post.save();
        }
    }
});
```

In action i get this model:

**Object {date: Thu May 15 2014 11:38:49 GMT+0400 (VOLT), 

body: "131313313131311313133", 

title: "131313313131311313133", 

__v: 0, id: "53746f09c7cc34da0d000001"…}

__ember1400142799882_meta: Meta

__v: 

0 body: (...) 

get body: function () 

{ set body: function (value) 

{ date: (...) get date: function () 

{ set date: function (value) 

{ id: (...) get id: function () 

{ set id: function (value) 

{ title: (...) get title: function () 

{ set title: function (value) {

__proto__: Object**

And next exception:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
This exception throws when i call post.deleteRecord()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution might be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839084).
You could define the `deletePost` action in the Route object and then access the model by `this.currentModel`.

**Template:**

```
<button {{action deletePost this}}>Delete post</button>
```

**Route:**

```
Blog.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  actions:{
      deletePost: function () {
        var post = this.currentModel;
        post.deleteRecord();
        post.save();
      }
  }

});
```